# FAQ Script Help

Tags: php

i have a string for example

```
 $str = "[H]Test[/H] My test string [H]Test2[/H] My second Test string";
```

and i want to make a list inside "[H]" and make them click able like

```
<a href="#faq-1">Test</a>
<a href="#faq-2">Test2</a>
```

and and also want to include this

```
<a name="faq-1"></a>Test
<a name="faq-2"></a>Test2
```

in `$str` any help please

Comment: Please consider doing some search before asking here.

Comment: I don't really understand. Do you want to make a list inside the [H] tags that links to the same place? Don't you mean you want a seperate list that links to elements in the text.

Comment: i want to do 2 things with the $STR
NO: list of all words or sentenses inside [H] [/H] tags
Like
<a href="#faq-1">Test</a>
<a href="faq-1"></a>Test
<a name="faq-2"></a>Test2 
<a href="#faq-2">Test2</a>
then also want to replace [H] [/H] tags like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with.

```
<?php

$str = "[H]Test[/H] My test string [H]Test2[/H] My second Test string";

/**
 * Helper class
 */
class FaqHelper {
    static $count = 1;
    static $listItems = array();
    static $prefix = 'faq-';

    static function GetList() {

        $items = '';
            foreach (self::$listItems as $id => $label) {
                $items .= '<li><a href="#' . self::$prefix . $id .'">' . $label . '</a></li>';
            }

        return '<ul>'. $items .'</ul>';
    }

    static function ReplaceCallback($matches)
    {
        $id = self::$count;
        $label = $matches[1];

        self::$listItems[$id] = $label;

        $res = '<span id="'. self::$prefix . $id .'">' . $label . '</span>';

        self::$count++;

        return $res;
    }
}

$text = preg_replace_callback(
    "#\[H\]([^\[]+)\[/H\]#",
    array('FaqHelper', "ReplaceCallback"),
    $str
);

$list = FaqHelper::GetList();

echo $list;
echo '<br /><br />';
echo $text;

?>
```

Comment: np. Note that I updated the snippet and moved the preg_replace_callback inside the FaqHelper class, further encapsulating the functionality inside the class. And please mark an answer as answer if it answered your question.

Comment: kjetilh please review this one also thanks 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061578/php-list-of-contents